# Does the tense of the verb in a nachdem clause need to be different from the one in the Hauptsatz?

Tags: conjunction, subordinate-clause, tense

The way I learned **nachdem** (the conjunction) is that the action in a Nebensatz with it is happening before the action in the Hauptsatz; through which (and also because of the immediate examples showed where i learned this) i assumed this means the tenses of the verbs in these clauses also differ.

Duolingo example i stumbled upon:

> "Nachdem die Leiterin **kündigt**, **werde** ich Chef."
> ("After the department head quits i'll become the boss")

The reason why it was a bit head-scratching is because i saw the verbs in the present tense in both (despite the action in the Hauptsatz happening in the future [because it's clear from the context the future is meant and so german uses the present tense in this case]) and because of my original assumption above.

So I would be really grateful to be confirmed that a clause with nachdem doesn't necessarily require a different verb tense than the one in the Hauptsatz but just the actual time of the actions in the two clauses have to be in sequence. Thanks

Comment: In general, German uses future tense more sparingly than English, but even in English a translation with the same tense, "After the department head quits I become the boss," is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one.

First off: you are right and "nachdem" means what happens in the *Nebensatz* introduced by it takes place before what happens in the *Hauptsatz*.

What makes things complicated is: obviously this is not storytelling, because in this case the *Hauptsatz* would have to be in *Präteritum* (and, because of that, the *Nebensatz* would be in *Plusquamperfect*):

> Nachdem die Leiterin gekündigt hatte, wurde ich Chef.

This would relate something that happened, regardless of it being part of a fictional story or one which really took place. You'd find this in a novel as well as in someones telling about his life.

But if it is not storytelling, then it never happened. If it never happened it might be *about to happen*, but that is in the future. You (will!) become boss, *whenever* the old boss resigns. But in this case "nachdem" is wrong and should be replaced by "wenn". The *Nebensatz* can then be in *Präsens*, because the prerequisite exists *now*, but a second "werden" would put the main sentence into its correct place: the future. The future is described by the *Futur* in German. You don't *become the boss*, but - only after the prerequisite (old boss resigns) is met - you *will* become the boss. But the old boss's resignation hasn't happened up to now and if she ever will resign we can't be sure about until she does.

> *Wenn* die Leiterin kündigt, werde ich Chef (werden).

It is quite often seen (but still incorrect) that "nachdem" (after) is used instead of "weil" (because), like this:

> Nachdem wir uns einig sind, tun wir es. (WRONG)

This is simply a misuse of "nachdem". True, we first needed to agree in order to do it, but we don't do it *after* we agree upon it. We do it *because* we agreed. The "after" is just an implication of the agreement being a prerequisite.

A fringe case is *storytelling* happening in *Präsens*. It is a device to draw the listener/reader into the story by giving him the feeling that the related story unfolds diectly before him right here and right now:

> Nachdem die Leiterin gekündigt hat, werde ich Chef.

This can be used in fictitious writing as a device, it would also befit the relation of something *right now*: you call your spouse and first you tell that the old boss finally resigned and - tadah! - you become the boss. But even here my gut feeling says the relationship between the two acts is not *temporal* but *causal*. The above sentence is more-or-less correct but I'd go with one of:

> Da die Leiterin gekündigt hat, werde ich Chef.
> Die Leiterin hat gekündigt und ich werde Chef.

Finally, I'd like to point out the translation you provided:

> *After* the department head quits *i'll* become the boss.

In your english version you yourself use *future tense* to signify that the action in the main sentence hasn't happened *yet*. This is exactly what I said above about *Futur*, therefore either the translation to English silently corrected the errror in German or the german translation of the english sentence was not correct. Take your pick.